# Webrequest not fully working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, httpwebrequest

I have a little problem. I want to do automatic searching, but there is a difference between the results from my webrequest (automatic) and the results if I just hit enter.

I want to results to be the exactly the same, the result should be the one I get when I hit enter.

Code request:

```
function showUser(str, str2)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
} 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "klanttabel.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent(str) + "&search2=" +       encodeURIComponent(str), true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Code query (wich gives me the right results)

```
if($search != ''){

$where[] = "( klant_id LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR  voornaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR     achternaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR email LIKE '%"        .$search."%' OR plaats LIKE '%"   .$search."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' ) ";

if($search2 != ''){
$where[] = " ( klant_id LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR voornaam   LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR   achternaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR email LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR   plaats LIKE '%"   .$search2."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%') ";
}
$query_where = (is_array($where))?" WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where):""; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant ".$query_where." ORDER BY klant_id DESC");
$i = 0;
}
```

I have two input fields, so that you can search for two different values. When I type them in and hit enter, it gives me the corresponding result.

But if I let it do it automatically, it just gives the result from the last field I typed in to.

So basically, it just searches for the last field. I think it has something to do with my input fields, so here is the code for that:

```
<form method="get">
<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" name="search" value="Naam..."    onkeyup="showUser(this.value)"></input><br />

<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" name="search2" value="Plaats..."  onkeyup="showUser(this.value)"></input><input type="submit" value="zoeken" name="submit2"   </input></form>
```

Comment: You might want to indent your code and use a library like jQuery to perform the requests. It will certainly make your life easier.

Comment: Okay,

but how should I do that? I don't have any experience with jQuery...

Comment: go to http://jquery.com and download the library.  There are some very good tutorials on the basics of what you wish to do.  Another library is yui - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant solution instead of using native `XMLHttpRequests` and all other workarounds is [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Also, other things:

- Input elements don't have a closing `</input>`.

A modified example that works on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9drS/.

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="Naam..." />

    <br />

    <input type="text" id="search2" name="search2" value="Plaats..." />

    <input type="submit" value="zoeken" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

$('#search, #search2').focus(function() { // clear on focus
    $(this).val('');
}).keyup(function() { // perform request on keyup
    $.ajax({ type: 'GET',
             url:  'klanttabel.php',
             data: { search:  $('#search').val(),
                     search2: $('#search2').val() },
             success: function(text) {
                 $("#txtHint").html(text);
             }
           });
});

});
```

Comment: That does not work at all. I downloaded jquery.js and included it as folowwing: `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

I have the js code like you posted...

Comment: @Andre Woons: You actually have to wrap the functions into `$(function() {...})` so that the functions are called when the page is done loading.

Comment: It now does not search automatically at all

Comment: Maybe you have msn or e-mail so that you can recieve all the code?

Comment: @Andre Woons: Could you first try out my fiddle I posted please? Maybe you can deduce how to implement exactly what you're after.

Comment: No can't seem to figure it out.. But the "not elegant" way worked except the correct search results.. So it has to do with the javascript. Can you find something that's wrong in there?

Comment: @Andre Woons: Could you perhaps host the PHP file along with the HTML/JavaScript you're using, so that it's possible to have a close look at what exactly goes wrong please?

Comment: I will upload the files this afternoon! Thanks for your help anyway!